# Радио на сайте

Tags: flash, php

Добрый день, дорогие программисты.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать код, чтобы музыка шла не из файла, а по ссылке, чтобы было радио на сайте, как переделать данный код.

```
<?
    $player=file_url('flashplayer.swf').'?file='.file_url('open.mp3');
?>
```

левые проигрыватели не давать... если можете то помогите с данным кодом

Answer (score 3):

[Uppod.](http://uppod.ru/)
Скрипт - плеер для сайта.
Все онлайн радиостанции им пользуются.